# Display options value related to selected option in mvc4 on view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a form. I want to display the options only related to the selected option, which select the user.

Select Degree

```
                    <select id="Degree">
                        @foreach (var v in Model.deg)
                        {
                            <option value=@v.Degree_Title>
                                @v.Degree_Title
                            </option> 

                        }
                    </select>
```

for example if the user selects the degree It only it related options will display on the next select box. Kindly response me soon.

Comment: I am getting value from database

Answer (score 0):

When you select a Degree (try to put it in DropDown in controller) and on select do autopostback which will populated the options related to selected degree.

Include this in javascript

```
function CausePostBack() {
        //alert('hello');
        var form1 = document.forms[0];
        if (!form1.onsubmit || (form1.onsubmit() != false)) {
            //alert('hello again');
            form1.submit();
        }
    }
```

and for the DropDown

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SomeName", (SelectList)ViewBag.ABC, new { @class = "DropDownList W150 ", onchange = "return CausePostBack();", value = @ViewBag.SelectedVal })
```